# Como fazer uma escolha aleatoria sem repetir PHP

Tags: php, html5

Estou fazendo uma disciplina de back end com PHP e não estou conseguindo resolver o seguinte exercício

```php
    <?php
    
    $animais_detalhes = [
        'cachorro' => [
            'nome' => 'Cachorro',
            'caracteristicas' => [
                ['mora numa casinha', 'cachorro/mora_numa_casinha.jpg'],
                ['tem patas', 'cachorro/tem_patas.jpg']
            ]
        ],
        'coruja' => [
            'nome' => 'Coruja',
            'caracteristicas' => [
                ['gosta da noite', 'coruja/gosta_da_noite.jpg'],
                ['tem olhos grandes', 'coruja/tem_olhos_grandes.jpg']
            ]
            ],
            'cavalo' => [
                'nome' => 'Cavalo',
                'caracteristicas' => [
                    ['tem pernas longas', 'cavalo/tem_pernas_longas.jpg'],
                    ['tem o casco duro', 'cavalo/tem_casco_duro.jpg']
                ]
        ],
        'gato' => [
                'nome' => 'Gato',
                'caracteristicas' => [
                    ['cospe bolas de pelo', 'gato/bola_de_pelo.jpg'],
                    ['anda por cima das coisas', 'gato/anda_cima_coisas.jpg']
                ]
        ]
    ];
    
    $animais = array_keys($animais_detalhes);
    $escolha_aleatoria = rand(0, 3);
    $animal_escolhido = $animais_detalhes[$animais[$escolha_aleatoria]];
    ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background: lightgreen;
            }

            .card-image img {
                object-fit: cover;
                object-position: center;
                width: 100%;
                max-height: 200px;
            }

            img.img-animal {
                object-fit: none;
                object-position: center;
                width: 100%;
                max-height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid p-4 pb-2" style="background: lightskyblue">
            <div class="row mt-2">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card card-image d-block">
                        <img src="./imagens/<?=$animal_escolhido['caracteristicas'][0][1]?>" class="card-img-top" alt="<?=$animal_escolhido['caracteristicas'][0][0]?>">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text"><?=$animal_escolhido['caracteristicas'][0][0]?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card card-image d-block">
                        <img src="./imagens/<?=$animal_escolhido['caracteristicas'][1][1]?>" class="card-img-top" alt="<?=$animal_escolhido['caracteristicas'][1][0]?>">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text"><?=$animal_escolhido['caracteristicas'][1][0]?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid p-2 mt-3" style="background: lightgreen">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="votar.php?apresentado=<?=$animais[$escolha_aleatoria]?>&escolhido=1">
                        <img width="256" src="./imagens/<?=$animais[$escolha_aleatoria] ?>.png" class="img-fluid" alt="mora numa casinha" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="votar.php?apresentado=<?=$animais[$escolha_aleatoria]?>&escolhido=2">
                        <!-- deixe dinâmico esta imagem abaixo -->
                        <img width="256" src="./imagens/cachorro.png" class="img-fluid" alt="mora numa casinha" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

O que preciso fazer é o seguinte:

> 1. Corrija o código de modo que o animal correto deixe de ser sempre o primeiro e passe então esta ordem a ser aleatória.
>
>    - Não há problemas em o animal correto ser o primeiro algumas vezes, o problema é ele ser sempre. Isso deveria ser randômico, aleatório.
> 2. Corrija o código de modo que o cachorro ou qualquer outro animal não apareça duas vezes como as únicas duas opções.
>
>    - É preciso mostrar o animal correto e outro animal, qualquer um, desde que não seja o mesmo.

Estou tentando da seguinte forma

```
$animais = array_keys($animais_detalhes);

$escolha_aleatoria = rand(0, count($animais)-1);

$animal_escolhido = $animais_detalhes[$animais[$escolha_aleatoria]];

$outroAnimal = rand(0, count($animais)-1);

if ($animal_escolhido == $outroAnimal){

    $outroAnimal = rand(0, count($animais)-1);
}

$escolhas = [$escolha_aleatoria, $outroAnimal];

shuffle($escolhas);

    $escolha1 = $escolhas[0];

    $escolha2 = $escolhas[1];
```

Porém as vezes ainda aparece o mesmo animal 2x.

Comment: Não consegui entender a pergunta. Vc quer que alguém faça o exercício pra vc?

Comment: Me explicasse como fazer seria suficiente, eu tentei algumas opções para deixar a imagem randomica e não aparecer 2x, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: uma dica, vc verifica apenas uma vez no 'if' se o animal não é duplicado, oque vc poderia fazer é usar o 'while' invés de 'if'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se tanto o `$animal_escolhido` quanto o outro devem ser escolhidos aleatoriamente, não precisa escolher um, e depois tentar pegar o outro. Você pode pegar ambos de uma só vez.

Basta pegar o array de chaves que você já tem (retornado por `array_keys`), embaralhá-lo com [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) e pegar as 2 primeiras chaves:

```
$chaves = array_keys($animais_detalhes);
shuffle($chaves);
$animal_escolhido = $animais_detalhes[$chaves[0]];
$outro = $animais_detalhes[$chaves[1]];
```

Como `shuffle` embaralha as chaves, eu garanto que ao pegar o primeiro e segundo elementos, eles serão aleatórios.

Inclusive, esta ideia de embaralhar todos os elementos e depois pegar somente a quantidade que você precisa é conhecido como [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

Em Vez de "IF"(se), usar "WHILE"(enquanto):

```
   while ($animal_escolhido == $outroAnimal){

        $outroAnimal = rand(0, count($animais)-1);´

    }
```

[Documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)